# Why is the unmarshaled YAML data empty?

Tags: go, struct, yaml, unmarshalling

I have a problem unmarshaling a simple slice of YAML data:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type myDataStruct struct {
    HTTP []struct {
        Name   string
        Target string
    }
}

func main() {
    yamlData := `
HTTP:
  - name: one
    target: http://wazaa
  - name: two
    target: http://wazii
`
    var myData myDataStruct
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlData), &myData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Print(myData)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Srb2DJVVZqN

The result is `{[]}` and my limited knowledge of Go does not help to understand why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify the mapping between labels used in the YAML source and Go struct fields, by default they will only be matched if only changing the first letter to lower matches.

E.g. the struct field `Name` will match `name`, but not `NAME`.

Specify the mapping for the `HTTP` field:

```
type myDataStruct struct {
    HTTP []struct {
        Name   string
        Target string
    } `yaml:"HTTP"`
}
```

With this change it works and outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](http://%7B%5B%7Bone%20http://wazaa%7D%20%7Btwo%20http://wazii%7D%5D%7D)):

```
{[{one http://wazaa} {two http://wazii}]}
```

It's good practice to provide mappings for all fields, so it'll continue to work if you rename the fields:

```
type myDataStruct struct {
    HTTP []struct {
        Name   string `yaml:"name"`
        Target string `yaml:"target"`
    } `yaml:"HTTP"`
}
```

Although in your case the default matching works for the `Name` and `Target` fields without providing the mappings.

Comment: Thank you. I had this in mind (and uses it just in case for the members such as `Name` in my example) and tried that on `HTTP` but I placed it in the wrong place (right after the opening `{ `). Now I see that it did not make much sense and the placement after the closing `}` is actually logical.